# wkhtmltopdf does not apply table-header-group css style

Tags: webkit, wkhtmltopdf, html2pdf

I'm developing an application that converts a web page containing a 1000 elements table to pdf.

I'm trying the wkhtmltopdf version 0.11.0 rc2, the resulting pdf looks great but... the column headers are not repeated on the pages and are visible only on the first page.

This seems to be a problem affecting also chromium engine, see http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=24826

Does anyone have a solution for this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately there is not a quick solution to the problem.. I'm going to use commercial products like http://www.winnovative-software.com/html-to-pdf-converter.aspx , it works and applies correctly the table headers.